# Circular Dependency in my SecurityConfig with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I tried to create a simple login module with Spring Boot and Spring Boot Security.

One of the updates happens in creating SecurityConfig is some of classes like
`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is now deprecated so I try the following code to make a SecurityConfig but unfortunately, I caught in a circular dependency.

Actually, I used Lombok to minimize the used of @Autowired in every field injection.

I tried the following approach:

1. I create another class for PasswordEncoder to avoid circular dependency if I used Password Encoder in the other parts of the Application.

**Error Message**.

```
Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌──->──┐
|  securityConfig defined in file [C:\Users\jgeronimo\Documents\jp_geronimo\sample_projects\spring-security-tutorial\target\classes\com\workshop\application\config\SecurityConfig.class]
└──<-──┘


Action:

Despite circular references being allowed, the dependency cycle between beans could not be broken. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle.
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthFilter jwtAuthFilter;

    private final JwtUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private final JwtAuthenticate jwtAuthenticate;

    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticate jwtAuthenticationEntryPointBean() throws Exception{
        return new JwtAuthenticate();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/**/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticate).and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        final DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
```

**Encoder.config**

```
@Configuration
public class EncoderConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Comment: `SecurityConfig` depends on `JwtAuthenticate` bean, which is instantiated in `SecurityConfig`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `JwtAuthenticate jwtAuthenticate` is redundant - remove it.

And while constructing the `SecurityFilterChain` refer to the method producing `JwtAuthenticate` Bean:

```
.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPointBean())
```

Comment: Thank you it removes the circular dependency but it creates new error:


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.core.context.DeferredSecurityContext

Comment: @JohnPauloA.Geronimo I almost certain that this apparent issue in not related to the cyclic dependency you've introduced. There's a little I can say about the cause from this chunk of exception message. You need to provide a **full** *exception stack-trace*, also *dependencies* in the `pom.xml` might contain a clue. I would advise to post a new Question with all the details related to the problem. That would allow you to draw and to collect opinions from a larger number of user (and you can share a link to the question here as well).

Comment: I already solved it by removing the spring-security-core and spring-security-web from the pom.xml. I just use spring-starter-security. Thank you very much sir. But may I know why spring-security-core and spring-security-web is not needed by spring?

Comment: @JohnPauloA.Geronimo [`spring-boot-starter-security`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security/3.0.0) as well as any other `spring-boot-starter` dependency basically is a **group** of dependencies. `spring-boot-starter-security` includes `spring-security-web` and `spring-security-config` (which in turn comes with `sping-context` and `spring-core`). You can examine it though the link to repository (or by selecting dependencies in your `pom.xml`).